# It is possible to add more field in a email/password auth with firebase and flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I am using Flutter and I decided to use Firebase. My authentification works with email/password but I need to register my users with more than just an email/password (name,age...).

I would like to add more fields when the user registers. Is this possible?

**I found 2 solutions :**

- Its possible to register a user with more fields
- Create a collection which contains all my users id with their infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to store this data (not the password) directly in the database. There is no other way of adding more details to a user record.

You also need to make sure you inform the user how you will be using/storing this data due to GDPR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer DevTard, Iam fixed now.